# Pattern in lua with anchors not matching

Tags: lua, lua-patterns

Why this does not match? I want to match the exact pattern 2 letters followed by 3 numbers

```
   s = "dd123"
   for w in string.gmatch(s, "^%a%a%d%d%d$") do
      print(w)
      matched = true
    end
```

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: single liner works. `print(string.match("dd123", "^%a%a%d%d%d$"))`

Comment: Its funny this shows up in the `regex` SO filtered tag.

Comment: @sln It had the regex tag, but I edited it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to see if a string matches a pattern, use `string.match` instead.

```
s = "dd123"
print(string.match(s, "^%a%a%d%d%d$")) -- dd123
```

`string.gmatch` is for finding all matches in a string, and doesn't work correctly with `^` and `$`.

Comment: Why `string.match` fails in the for loop?

Comment: `string.gmatch` doesn't allow anchoring to the start of the string (this is in [the manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-string.gmatch)). I'm not sure why `$` is allowed though.