# lua not handling anchors in string.find or string.match

Tags: lua, anchor, string-matching

This has been asked before at [Pattern in lua with anchors not matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26000428/pattern-in-lua-with-anchors-not-matching) however I have a test case that shows that it still doesn't appear to work:

```
patterns = {
    'a@b',
    '^a@b',
    'a@b.com',
    'my-a@b',
    'my-a@b.com',
    'a@b.com$',
    '^this-is-my-a@b.com',
    'this-is-my-a@b.com$',
    '^this-is-my-a@b.com$',
}

test = "this-is-my-a@b.com"

for _, pattern in ipairs(patterns) do
    print(pattern .. ": " .. test .. "\n\tfind: " .. (test:find(pattern) or 'nil') .. "\n\tmatch: " .. (test:match(pattern) or 'nil'))
    print(pattern .. ": " .. test .. "\n\tfind: " .. (string.find(test, pattern) or 'nil') .. "\n\tmatch: " .. (string.match(test, pattern) or 'nil'))
end
```

I did the separate `test:find` vs `string.find(test...)` just to be sure there were no shenanigans.

Can someone enlighten me on how I can get my anchored patterns to work?

Comment: lua version is 5.1.4

Comment: `.` and `-` are special char in context of regex. so you need escape them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of the characters you are using (like `.` and `-`) have special meaning in pattern matching and you need to escape them. For example, using `^this%-is%-my%-a@b%.com` and `this%-is%-my%-a@b%.com$` should produce the expected results.

Comment: I'd already struggled through that situation, and got caught again!  Thanks :)